# What versions of IE is Razor/MVC3 compatible with?

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

I am writing a website using C# razor code.  I'm a total newbie when it comes to this web stuff (i am a c# programmer).  Anyway, what do I need to worry about with regard to backward compatibility?  .NET version?  IE version?  Chrome version?  IE 8 and latest Chrome seem to work fine.  I just do not want to create a web site and have nobody able to use it.

Also on a related note, how would i go about installing IE6/IE7 for compatibility testing purposes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are "compatible" with all of the browsers **you** care to support.

You seem to be confusing server side and client side technologies - Razor/MVC3 are server side technologies that can render *anything* to the client, be it IE6, Chrome or Opera.

**You** have control over what is rendered and can ensure the client code that is returned will work with whatever clients you care for it to work with.

Comment: I think it's alright to be confused about browser support if you're coming from WebForms and don't know how MVC works. Especially considering all the hand holding WebForms does in terms of generating html for you.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net / MVC / Razor is a framework for producing the html content; as long as the server you host on is capable to produce it then as per regular html when it gets to the browser.

The issues with browser compatibility is the usual fight of the web programmer :-)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET, including MVC and the Razor engine, execute on the server to build HTML to send to the client (the web browser, in this case, IE).  So it doesn't matter what version of IE you are running for Razor to work. What matters is that the HTML your Razor pages generate is compatible with the web browsers you want your application to work with.